# Rsync: Prioritise files and folders

Tags: rsync

I'm copying a large directory from one computer to another using rsync. Is there a way to tell rsync I would like it to copy some files and / or folders first, before others so that I can start working with them immediately?

Comment: see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-control-file-order-in-rsync-871930/ - it looks like it can't be done except by using multiple rsync statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-control-file-order-in-rsync-871930/ - it looks like it can't be done except by using multiple rsync statements, sorry.